# How to write this statement more compactly without a ++ operator?

Tags: python

Here's what I want to write:

```
groups[m][n] = groups[m - 1][n] or ++gid
```

Here's what I have to write:

```
g = groups[m - 1][n]
if g:
    groups[m,n] = g
else:
    gid += 1
    groups[m][n] = gid
```

Is there no more compact way of writing that in Python simply because it lacks a `++` operator?

---

A larger sample from a method I'm working on:

```
groups = [[0] * self.columns] * self.rows
gid = 0
for m in xrange(self.rows):
    for n in xrange(self.columns):
        stone = self[m, n]
        if stone == self[m - 1, n]:
            if groups[m - 1][n]:
                groups[m][n] = groups[m - 1][n]
            else:
                gid += 1
                groups[m][n] = gid
        elif stone == self[m, n - 1]:
            if groups[m][n - 1]:
                groups[m][n] = groups[m][n - 1]
            else:
                gid += 1
                groups[m][n] = gid
```

I think it's a lot harder to read when I have to blow it out like that, plus I'm evaluating `m-1` twice... I'm not sure how I can condense it though.

---

This is what I came up with:

I created a wrapper class around `int`:

```
class Int(object):
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i

    def pre(self, a=1):
        self.i += a
        return Int(self.i)

    def post(self, a=1):
        cpy = Int(self.i)
        self.i += a
        return cpy

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.i)

    def __nonzero__(self):
        return self.i != 0
```

Which can be used like this:

```
def group_stones(self):
    groups = [[None for _ in xrange(self.cols)] for _ in xrange(self.rows)]
    gid = Int(0)
    for m in xrange(self.rows):
        for n in xrange(self.cols):
            stone = self[m, n]
            if stone == self[m - 1, n]:
                groups[m][n] = groups[m - 1][n] or gid.pre()
            elif stone == self[m, n - 1]:
                groups[m][n] = groups[m][n - 1] or gid.pre()
            else:
                groups[m][n] = gid.pre()
```

Much like I would do in other languages.

Comment: What's the purpose of writing this more compactly? Write a function.

Comment: @GregHewgill: How? I can't pass by reference either.

Comment: Numbers in Python are immutable! `num += 1` it is just `num = num + 1`, and `num` on the left side is link to the new object.

Comment: @astynax: Well, x+=1 works, but it doesn't return the new value, which is what I'd need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gid = [0] # list - mutable object

def incremented(gid):
    gid[0] += 1
    return gid[0]

groups[m][n] = groups[m - 1][n] or incremented(gid)
```

You can add some "magic" to your Int class:

```
class C(object):
    ...
    def __add__(self, other):
        self.i += other
        return self.__class__(self.i)
    def __radd__(self, other):
        cpy = self.__class__(self.i)
        self.i += other
        return cpy

>>> print Int(2) + 1 # pre
3
>>> i = Int(2)
>>> print 1 + i # post
2
>>> print i
3
```

Comment: Ah.. I believe the concept is called boxing. Python doesn't have an `Integer` class that is better suited for this?

Comment: @Mark, numbers in Python - immutable objects. Once instantiated Number cannot be changed. Any operation with numbers produces new number-object.

Comment: Yes, but how does that conflict with what I just said? The integer is immutable, that's why you're "boxing" it (putting it inside a mutable class). I'm asking if there isn't one built-in, rather than abusing a list object?

Comment: @Mark, All number types in Python are immutable by the concept, same as a strings and tuples. There are no mutable number classes (out of the box).

Comment: I don't think you're following me. I know numbers themselves are immutable -- I thought we were past that -- I was asking there was a *mutable class* that acts as a wrapper (box) around the integer to *make* it mutable. I will take that as a *no* and define one myself.

Comment: @Mark, sorry for my english... Answer is "no". Your wrapper is quite good

Comment: Maybe I miss-read you the first time. It's getting late here. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Technically more compact, but not really more readable nor less DRY:

```
groups[m][n], gid = (groups[m-1][n], gid) if groups[m-1][n] else (gid+1, gid+1)
```

Less compact (for a single usage, at least), more readable:

```
def test_or_inc(val, accum):
    return (val, accum) if val else (accum+1, accum+1)

groups[m][n], gid = test_or_inc(groups[m-1][n], gid)
```

---

Another option is to make `gid` something you *can* pass by reference... such as a property of an object, or an item in a list.

Comment: I thought for a second you weren't actually incrementing the variable, but then I saw you did a list-assign...sneaky, but you're right, it's kind of ugly.

Answer (score 1):

If you put the gid generation in a function you can do that. For example (using the global scope):

```
gid = 0
def newgid(): global gid; gid += 1; return gid
```

Now you can write:

```
groups[m][n] = groups[m - 1][n] or newgid()
```

Of course it would be better to put the gid and newgid in its own class or in the class where your other methods are.